# How to track audit information for SSIS packages running from scheduled jobs

Tags: sql, ssis, audit

Daily we are running 140 ssis packages from jobs as per the requirement.

I have to track all ssis packages information into the Audit table with out updating ssis packages

```
i.e Rowcount,jobname,packagename,runduration,runstatus etc.
```

How can i do this ??

Comment: I doubt you can get the rowcount without touching the packages.  What if the package performs more than one operation?

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you running? Your request to not modify packages, as Eric has identified, is likely to be incompatible with your request to capture those data points.

Comment: If you replace the clause "with out updating ssis packages" to "with minimal changes to the SSIS packages" then you might actually get some answers.